# using JSONcpp in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jsoncpp

Is there any way to create .lib that will work on VS2010? Even amalgamation version of JSONcpp doesn't work(( It is throws me LNK2028 and LNK2019 errors.

Answer (score 2):

Amalgamation should work on VS2010. Make sure you add the path to Additional Include Directories.

Comment: I am getting below error while trying to run on VS2010. "ERROR:  Visual Studio 12 (2013) with _MSC_VER=1800 is the oldest supported compiler with sufficient C++11 capabilities". Any clue ?